# Is there a way to have this code in a regular module and not in a worksheet module?

Tags: excel, vba, show

I would like to know if there's a way that the following code could work as a regular module with modifications.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Offset(1, 0).Resize(3).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: No, It is an event that needs to be tied to the sheet.  Can you explain more what you want to do?  Maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: So, there's hidden rows on my sheet. I created a button made of a shape with a macro so that when you click on it, three rows that were hidden, appears. The thing is, it needs to be three rows under when your cursor is on a field.

Comment: `Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(3).EntireRow.Hidden = False` in a the sub called by your button.